# How to generate dynamically adding the rows in table in jasper report for JAVA

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have .jrxml with generating the PDF and everthing works fine. But sometimes i need to add dynamically another item of table's items.

How to do that? I'm new in this field and need only one time to create this pdf.

I have this json:

```
{
  "customerName": "derr",
  "customerEmail": "sss.dd@gmail.com",
  "invoiceNumber": "1",
  "invoiceAmount": "180",
  "invoiceDate": "2021-08-30",
  "poNumber": "234234",
  "productName": "Hilton Milano",
  "price": "180",
  "vat": "0",
  "lineTotal": "180",
  "currency": "EUR"
}
```

And i want to change to this json:

```
{
  "customerName": "derr",
  "customerEmail": "sss.dd@gmail.com",
  "items": [
    {
      "invoiceNumber": "1",
      "invoiceAmount": "180",
      "invoiceDate": "2021-08-30",
      "poNumber": "234234",
      "productName": "Hilton Milano",
      "price": "180",
      "vat": "0",
      "lineTotal": "180",
      "currency": "EUR"
    },
    {
      "invoiceNumber": "2",
      "invoiceAmount": "180",
      "invoiceDate": "2021-08-30",
      "poNumber": "45455",
      "productName": "Item2",
      "price": "180",
      "vat": "0",
      "lineTotal": "180",
      "currency": "EUR"
    }
  ]
```

}

main.jrxm

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.17.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.17.0-6d93193241dd8cc42629e188b94f9e0bc5722efd  -->
<jasperReport
    xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="invoicePdf" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="30" rightMargin="30" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="50" uuid="7d0a15bc-a154-4191-a8d5-465fd3e2f940">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.5"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="140"/>
    <property name="ireport.callouts" value="##Fri Mar 30 16:17:30 NPT 2012"/>
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="dataset1" uuid="20b79c3c-1fd4-42fd-ad01-d369a2f1a0cd"/>
    <subDataset name="Table Dataset 1" uuid="3839d134-0267-43a2-854f-041071168b36"/>
    <subDataset name="Table Dataset 2" uuid="1975b989-32d5-4346-ad08-b457e77b1e29"/>
    <parameter name="customerName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="customerEmail" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="invoiceNumber" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="invoiceAmount" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="invoiceDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="poNumber" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="logo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="paymentType" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="itemNo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="productName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="price" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="qty" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="vat" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="lineTotal" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="currency" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <group name="Total">
        <groupExpression>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="4"/>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="44">
                <rectangle>
                    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="310" y="14" width="223" height="25" backcolor="#C7D8ED" uuid="e811544e-cfab-4550-8286-bfdaf44eee65"/>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineColor="#666666"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </rectangle>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="322" y="17" width="121" height="20" uuid="c011ebd4-5c97-442e-a53f-2d7d7c8ad948"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                        <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text>
                        <![CDATA[Balance Due ]]>
                    </text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="424" y="17" width="89" height="20" uuid="90f7d030-b646-407e-ab10-0bb7dcd5f5ea"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <textFieldExpression>
                        <![CDATA[$P{invoiceAmount}]]>
                    </textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="2" y="6" width="531" height="1" uuid="183f46f9-d5ef-4358-85b5-b85fa132de92"/>
                </line>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <title>
        <band height="84" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="2" y="10" width="553" height="29" forecolor="#B9B9B9" uuid="9b5e2863-aa0c-4549-ae8b-f7d1cbd23db9"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="18" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[Invoice]]>
                </text>
            </staticText>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="126" height="50" uuid="dd60c047-d53d-413d-9d78-3fb63659601b"/>
                <imageExpression>
                    <![CDATA[$P{logo}]]>
                </imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="110" splitType="Stretch">
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="315" y="1" width="218" height="96" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#C7D8ED" uuid="1f1fcf4d-aad5-4412-89d6-f611c77ca62b"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineColor="#666666"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="325" y="3" width="93" height="20" uuid="df764129-cd10-4ab5-9a53-dea9049661ca"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[Invoice Number :]]>
                </text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="325" y="28" width="93" height="20" uuid="8124942b-695d-456f-89af-1d2173f76f7c"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[Invoice Date :]]>
                </text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="325" y="52" width="93" height="20" uuid="ad5877e4-f5f7-4590-8ff9-5fe28bc03f1c"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[Payment Type :]]>
                </text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="325" y="76" width="93" height="20" uuid="c8255484-a451-45ee-9edd-00c46c10f035"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[PO Number :]]>
                </text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="434" y="52" width="88" height="20" uuid="3bfc9280-bf70-4e75-a78a-059c6c0db751"/>
                <textFieldExpression>
                    <![CDATA[$P{paymentType}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="434" y="76" width="88" height="20" uuid="e73d80ee-3f41-4287-adee-05fc0662c19b"/>
                <textFieldExpression>
                    <![CDATA[$P{poNumber}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="23" width="167" height="20" uuid="49c625cf-a655-4d84-87ad-acd5c518abce"/>
                <textFieldExpression>
                    <![CDATA[$P{customerEmail}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="167" height="20" uuid="688ecd1e-e722-4fd0-ba48-be1a00e2ed56"/>
                <textFieldExpression>
                    <![CDATA[$P{customerName}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="434" y="3" width="88" height="20" uuid="bc17e675-9dc6-4bbd-bea7-b34279434b79"/>
                <textFieldExpression>
                    <![CDATA[$P{invoiceNumber}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="MMMMM dd, yyyy">
                <reportElement x="434" y="28" width="88" height="20" uuid="ac9b4d6e-5f0e-4f96-839a-de364ec4c1e1"/>
                <textFieldExpression>
                    <![CDATA[$P{invoiceDate}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="2" y="90" width="53" height="20" uuid="6445e47d-6bff-4a50-a972-f32ed369663b"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[Currency :]]>
                </text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="59" y="90" width="86" height="20" uuid="732a0a0e-cdd1-416c-b27a-d17ee88cbe5f"/>
                <textFieldExpression>
                    <![CDATA[$P{currency}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="27" splitType="Stretch">
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="2" y="2" width="531" height="20" backcolor="#C0D4EC" uuid="92d1cf50-6c32-45de-bb2b-45e6156df9c7"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineColor="#666666"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="5" y="4" width="50" height="20" uuid="10c2e6ed-df03-4c67-8c98-7cadb4ffc402"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[Pos.]]>
                </text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="70" y="4" width="179" height="20" uuid="d0f2894e-ce61-49f1-a644-3aeda6d84872"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[Description]]>
                </text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="265" y="4" width="80" height="20" uuid="ebf8ca5f-0378-4615-9092-c3ce3bef6e70"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[Amount]]>
                </text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="358" y="4" width="80" height="20" uuid="f2de7d8f-dfaf-46c8-9331-8a5a72eef41c"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[Vat%]]>
                </text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="454" y="4" width="79" height="18" uuid="725f0632-7166-4eff-be2e-b88e176d7ef0"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="12" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text>
                    <![CDATA[Price]]>
                </text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="29" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="5" y="5" width="54" height="20" uuid="0528046a-26fc-4f5a-b7bc-21e94ff7df04"/>
                <textFieldExpression>
                    <![CDATA[$P{itemNo}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="70" y="5" width="167" height="20" uuid="bcc78fda-a62f-4a3b-9b53-7b4286e98825"/>
                <textFieldExpression>
                    <![CDATA[$P{productName}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="265" y="5" width="57" height="20" uuid="4b550cd8-c1bb-4205-9239-0e65592b778a"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression>
                    <![CDATA[$P{price}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="358" y="5" width="75" height="20" uuid="c2f3c7b5-6323-4475-8dc7-1a3d6c7a15bd"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression>
                    <![CDATA[$P{vat}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="448" y="5" width="64" height="20" uuid="cf8302d4-9cf6-4e3e-bd0e-ba820fac9430"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression>
                    <![CDATA[$P{lineTotal}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Also the code that generates PDF

```
    // Generating PDF invoice
    public byte[] generateInvoiceFor(String pdfInvoiceParameters) {
        try {
            LOGGER.debug("Generating pdf invoice for user: [{}]", "x");

            validateXmlFormat(pdfJasperReportXml);
            // Load invoice jrxml template.
            JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfJasperReportXml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
            JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);

            // Create parameters map.
            Map<String, Object> parameters = buildParametrsMap(pdfInvoiceParameters);

            // Fill the template with parameters map.
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());

            return JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
        } catch (SAXException saxEx) {
            LOGGER.error("XML format is not correct for following PDF template {} and exception has raised : {} ", pdfJasperReportXml, saxEx.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (JsonProcessingException jsonEx) {
            LOGGER.error("Json params format error for {} and exception has raised : {} ", pdfInvoiceParameters, jsonEx.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error has occured {}", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Fill template order parametres
    private Map<String, Object> buildParametrsMap(String pdfInvoiceParameters) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Map<String, Object> pdfInvoiceParams = mapper.readValue(pdfInvoiceParameters, Map.class);

//         pdfInvoiceParams.put("logo", resourcesInvoiceImagesPath + "logo.jpg");
        return pdfInvoiceParams;
    }
```

So actually need to add dynamically to add the items if they present in parameters like first row item1 with its price, then new row item2 with its price and etc.

[image]

Comment: Could you do it? I am looking also for similar answers.